# IcCube - Incremental load with different triggers and different strategies

Tags: iccube

I understand that Incremental strategy is defined at Schema level.
I have an incremental load already set-up and working fine, a rule in the scheduler launches it every hour. (Rule 1)

Now, I want to generate a full reload of the schema, but based on another trigger data. Here are the rules I want to manage :
[image]

Is it possible to setup the Rule 2? and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported. You would need to setup an external process for that and perform a full load using a command as described in this page: [www](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/using/cube_management.php).